# num_leaves selection in LightGBM?

Tags: machine-learning, hyperparameters, lightgbm

Is there any rule of thumb to initialize the `num_leaves` parameter in `lightgbm`. For example for `1000` featured dataset, we know that with `tree-depth` of `10`, it can cover the entire dataset, so we can choose this accordingly, and search space for tuning also get limited.

But in `lightgbm`, how we can roughly guess this parameters, otherwise its search space will be pretty large while using grid-search method.

Any intuition on selecting this parameters will be helpful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The best recommendation, that I bumped into is [this awesome summary by Laurae](https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM/issues/695#issuecomment-315591634) on lightgbm github. As always, this very much depends on your data.

My personal rule of thumb based on limited kaggle experience is to start by trying values in the range `[10,100]`. But if you have a solid heuristic to choose tree depth you can always use it and set `num_leaves` to `2^tree_depth - 1`

Comment: why `-1`, why not just `2^tree_depth`?

Comment: The tree of depth one has 1 leaf/node, depth two-  (1+2) leaves, depth three - (1+2+4). The rest you get by induction

Comment: I think leaf should mean terminal nodes, so tree of depth  n could have 2^n leaves/terminal-nodes,, and 2^n - 1 non-terminal nodes. https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Parameters-Tuning.html confirms my understanding. But I'm not sure of the intuition behind 2^n - 1 num_leaves.

Comment: I fail to see where does the page confirm the assumption that leaves are terminal nodes.  The number of leaves in the layer n of a tree is 2^(n-1), but this does not relate to `num_leaves`

Comment: For "the assumption that leaves are terminal nodes", I'm looking at the line `Theoretically, we can set num_leaves = 2^(max_depth) to obtain the same number of leaves as depth-wise tree.`. I think for **a tree of depth one, it has one split or non-terminal node, and two leaves/terminal nodes**. That saying tree of depth one has 1 leaf/node is _NOT_ correct.

Comment: Ah, i think they have not been explicit in that statement. You can see at the end of that paragraph, that they actually quote the value 2**7-1 for the example that they give. Throughout the docs you will see that the maximum value is odd and not even. One other example is the parameter docs by Laurae: https://sites.google.com/view/lauraepp/parameters -> `Maximum leaves`: "On LightGBM, the maximum leaves must be tuned with the maximum depth together.
To get xgboost behavior, set the maximum leaves to 2^depth - 1." You can verify your hypothesis by building a tree of depth 1 and plot it

Comment: 31 is random, see [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/issues/3177#issuecomment-647206218)